# To interact with smart contract without gasprice

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, web3-java, azure-blockchain-workbench

I am using web3j java library to deploy and to interact with the smart contract. When I tried to send a transaction that invoke a function in smart contract by setting the gas price to 0 and gas limit to DefaultGasProvider.GAS_LIMIT. I am getting the below exception.

How to fix this issue?

With Remix and MetaMask it works without any issue. What am I missing when using web3j, any pointers would be of great help.

```
org.web3j.protocol.exceptions.TransactionException: Transaction has failed with status: 0x0. Gas used: 4300000. (not-enough gas?)
```

Answer (score -1):

Only solidity ^0.4.25 supports sending transactions with gas price 0.